# Under what circumstances would [ [ UIApplication sharedApplication ] keyWindow ] return nil?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, uiapplication

In some cases `[[ UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow ]` returns `nil`.

On some devices it's happening pretty often but in general it's sporadic

Anyone know the reasons it would return nil?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15623745/308315

Answer (score 2):

...When happens a transition form one window to another, i suppose. Users can't see any transitions, but they happen.

In iPhone OS 2.0 to iPhone 3.1.3, one example is immediately after you sent the message `play` to a `MPMoviePlayerController` instance:

```
[[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:[@"http://someurl"]]play];
```

There might be also other situations.

Comment: +1 I'm pretty sure all the system provided modal views do this. The image picker view for example. You will get it before the window loads in the app delegate as well.